# How to fetch only first entity from Core data?

Tags: objective-c, core-data

It may looks like a newbie question, but I really am. I try to fetch only first object from Core data. But I try to figure out how could I done this?

For example, it may have 100 object in Core data for specific entity. I just need the first one. Could you give me your advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Fetch limits](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPerformance.html)

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setFetchLimit:1];
```

Comment: actually, since he's only looking for the first entity, wouldn't it be [request setFetchLimit:1]?

Comment: You would also want to include a sort descriptor as well, right?  Since core data does note guarantee any order, correct?

Comment: Thank for all of you, guys. I can use this solution for my project now. :)